# Export class from namespace

Tags: php, namespaces

I namespaced a class to make use of aliases to provide shorthands for some long class names:

```
namespace some_namespace;
use \VeryLongClassnameWhichIUseOften as Short;

class MyClass {
  public static method do_stuff() {

    Short::do_something(Short::do_other_stuff());

  }
}
```

Now there is some third party code that expects `MyClass` in the global namespace.

Can I somehow export `MyClass` to the global namespace?

I tried

```
class \MyClass {
  ...
}
```

but apparently that is no allowed (unexpected T_NS_SEPARATOR, expecting T_STRING).

I also tried this:

```
namespace some_namespace {
  use \VeryLongClassnameWhichIUseOften as Short;

  class MyClass {
    ...
  }
}

namespace {
  use \some_namespace\MyClass as MyClass;
}
```

which doesn't throw any additional error but MyClass still isn't available in the global namespace (Class 'MyClass' not found). I don't quite understand why.

Comment: Third party code that expects *your* user-defined class in the global namespace?

Comment: Yes, it's a plugin system where I can choose the class name but not the namespace.

Comment: How does it work? Where do you define which class it should use? If it's some config file or something, have you tried setting the value to `\MyNamespace\MyClass`?

Comment: Class 'MyNamespaceMyClass' not found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this in your global namespace:

```
use \some_namespace\MyClass as MyClass;
```

I believe it should work.

Edit: It does not. This should work:

```
class_alias('\some_namespace\MyClass', 'MyClass');
```

Comment: Hm, this works: http://codepad.viper-7.com/ED55Ml Investigating what's the difference...

Comment: Ah, yeah it does not work. Have you tried `class_alias('\some_namespace\MyClass', 'MyClass')`?

Comment: Ok, here my results: The `use` method works only if the use is in the same file as the `MyClass::method()` call. If it's in the file with the `class MyClass` definition, *although it's in the global namespace*, it doesn't work. The `class_alias()` method, however, works - thanks. :)