# Using a namespace in an extended class

Tags: php, codeigniter, namespaces, propel

I'm using Propel together with CodeIgniter.  I made a `MY_Model` class (which extends `CI_Model`) that uses its constructor to load Propel.

In case you're curious:

```
class MY_Model extends CI_Model{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        require_once '/propel/runtime/lib/Propel.php';
        Propel::init('/build/conf/project-conf.php');
        set_include_path('/build/classes'.PATH_SEPARATOR.get_include_path());
    }
}
```

So, now when I make a new CodeIgniter model, it will load up Propel for me.  Thing is, I added namespaces to a few of the Propel-generated models.  I figured I could add the `use Reports;` line inside the model's constructor, but nope.

```
class Reports_model extends MY_Model{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        use Reports;
    }
}
```

This gives me

> syntax error, unexpected T_USE

Ok, I thought, let's try putting it outside the constructor:

```
class Reports_model extends MY_Model{
    use Reports;

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Now I get a longer error:

> syntax error, unexpected T_USE, expecting T_FUNCTION

As a last resort, I added the `use Reports;` before the class declaration:

```
use Reports;

class Reports_model extends MY_Model{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Now I get even more errors!

> The use statement with non-compound name 'Reports' has no effect
>   Class 'ReportsQuery' not found

In another function in the class, I have a line that does `$report = ReportsQuery::create();`.

So, how can I get the `use Reports;` line to work?  I really don't feel like adding `Reports\` *everywhere*.

How can I make it so I can do:

```
$report = ReportsQuery::create();
```

instead of:

```
$report = Reports\ReportsQuery::create();
```

Comment: Good question... and my follow up would be why isn't PHP able to find the `Reports` namespace? my guess would be that the location of the `Reports_model` class makes it such that PHP doesn't know where to find `Reports`. Sorry, I'm not a namespace expert, but you may want to ask this in the Propel google group if you don't get an answer here!

Comment: @jakerella: The `Reports` namespace only exists in Propel's models.  My guess is that `MY_Model`'s constructor wasn't called yet, so PHP doesn't know where the namespace is.

Comment: Riiiight... hrm. Maybe you'll just have to always init Propel versus in the model constructor? In other words, put it in some sort of startup area (not terribly familiar with CI).

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to declare a class' namespace *before* other code also does so.  I also know nothing about namespaces.  I'm just using them because this is a new project, and I want to keep the new tables separate.

Comment: why not include the file in index.php? 2nd, using a PSR autoloader namespace will be save you lot of headaches. 3rd, if you wanto to use namespace, use laravel.... Laravel makes things like this piece of cake.

Comment: @itachi: I don't want to load it in the index because I only want to load it when I need it.  What's a "PSR autoloader namespace"?  Also what's "laravel"?  I'm already using CodeIgniter.

Comment: well.... Laravel is one of the php frameworks which extensively uses namespaces and thus easier to load 3rd party libraries.

Comment: @itachi: I'd rather not switch frameworks at this point in the project.

Comment: FYI on laravel, it was made by the same guy who started CI, and it's pretty nice. Not saying you should switch now, but maybe for your next project. ;)

Comment: @jakerella: I may just have to look into it then :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the `use` keyword doesn't do what I though it did.  That just tells PHP where to look for a class.

What I needed to do was use the `namespace` keyword to declare that my class was in the `Reports` namespace.  I then had to tell it to use `MY_Model` from the global namespace.

```
namespace Reports;
use MY_Model;

class Reports_model extends MY_Model{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

<sub>I could also do `class Reports_model extends \MY_Model{` instead of the `use MY_Model;` line.</sub>

Problem now is that CodeIgniter can't find `Reports_model` because it's now inside the `Reports` namespace, and not the global namespace.  I found the solution to that in another StackOverflow question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14008411/206403).

There is a function called [`class_alias`](http://php.net/class_alias) that's basically magic.

```
namespace Reports;
use MY_Model;

class_alias('Reports\Reports_model', 'Reports_model', FALSE);

class Reports_model extends MY_Model{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

And that works perfectly!

Comment: actually you can just add `\\` before the namespace and access it in glbal scope. nayjest probably wanted to say that.

Comment: @itachi: I do mention that in my answer: `extends \MY_Model`.  Problem is, I'm using CodeIgniter, so I can't edit it to add the slashes.

Answer (score 0):

Just prefix all classes without namespaces by "\" in code with namespaces

Comment: But, how do I get my code to be *in* the namespace?  *That's* the question here.

Comment: Code below "namespace BlahBlahBlah;" will be in namespace BlahBlahBlah.
If you defined some class there, you will able to use that class outside with \BlahBlahBlah\MyClass
Or add "use BlahBlahBlah\MyClass;" to the file where it will be used  and access it by class name without namespace. Note that in "use" construction you must specify full namespaced class name, php can't import all classes of some namespace that way.

If you writing "use" inside class, it will be interpreted as adding of trait to this class, you don't need it.